# FirefoxOS marketplace after update (Fx0 device)

Tags: firefox-os, if-none-match

I and at least some other users cannot use the Marketplace after updating the marketplace. The phone loads the app but the page just sits there. I traced the network and I see that no content is returned from the server. If I remove the header `If-None-Match` I do get a response. Clearing the cache, changing the system date does not resolve the issue. Can someone help me to resolve this?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Was I wrong to ask for help with a problem I'm having????

Comment: SO isn't a tech support. If you have problem with the market place. Ask on mozilla forum and fill a bug on bugzilla.

Answer (score 0):

**Basically this device is riddled with spyware. You should update it immedately.**

Comment: Updating to the lastest also works, however that has other implications that may be less desirable.